# Fetch the respective number of files uploaded on each upload control on submitting the form on MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload, multifile-uploader

I have ***n*** number of multi file upload controls in a form. Is there any way to retrieve the multiple files uploaded on each of the input controls separately on submitting the form on asp.net MVC. Now, I'm getting all the files combined.

**Note:** : All these upload controls are dynamically added and not fixed

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("IpadUpload", "ReferenceDatabase", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div id="multiple">
        <input type="file" class="multiple" name="files" multiple />
        <input type="file" class="multiple" name="files" multiple />
    </div>
    
    <button class="btn btn-default">Upload</button>
}

public FileResult IpadUpload(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
}
```

[image]

After submitting
[image]

Any suggestions on how to retrieve the multiple files uploaded on each of the input controls separately? I have googled a lot, but no hope

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming your file input controls and having the below signature for method

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("IpadUpload", "ReferenceDatabase", FormMethod.Post,new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{    
<div id="multiple">
    <input type="file" class="multiple" name="filesControl1" multiple />
    <input type="file" class="multiple" name="filesControl2" multiple />
</div>

<button class="btn btn-default">Upload</button>
}

public FileResult IpadUpload(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> filesControl1, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> filesControl2 )
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, The number of upload controls are not fixed, It's created dynamically